# How can I see which partitions in the apache Kafka broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

Is it possible in Apache kafka through the kafkacat command to see which partition is located in broker?
for example:
broker 0
partition 1,2

broker 1
partition 0,1,2

Many thanks

I use the .\bin\win\kafkacat -L -b hostname:port command it shows BROKERS and a partitions, but does not show a relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `kafka-topics --describe` command. This will show replica placement and leader partition by broker IDs

But that same information is in latest release of `kcat -L` output

```
 1 topics:
  topic "foo" with 3 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
    partition 1, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
    partition 2, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
```

`1001` maps to `broker.id` in `server.properties`... If you want a reverse lookup to a host/IP, then you need to do extra work.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understood you correctly.
output of kcat.                          topic "my-main_topic" with 4 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 0, replicas: 0, isrs: 0
    partition 1, leader 2, replicas: 2, isrs: 2
    partition 2, leader 2, replicas: 2, isrs: 2
    partition 3, leader 0, replicas: 0, isrs: 0  . partition 0 found in broker 0, partition 1 found in broker 2.

Comment: If you have 3 brokers, you should create the topic with more than one replica, but yes